# How do I format a list of numbers for JSON API payload?

Tags: python, json, list, api, post

I need to post some JSON to a REST API. I want the payload to look like this:

```
{"id": {2342,2354,5676,7423}}
```

The numbers need to come from a list:

```
userid = [2342,2354,5676,7423]
```

I tried to loop through the list using something like this:

```
payload = {"id": {",".join([str(i) for i in userid])}}
```

But that gives me a quote around all the numbers which then fails:

```
{'id': {'2342,2354,5676,7423'}}
```

How can I insert those numbers into JSON without the quotes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible. `{"id": {2342,2354,5676,7423}}` is not a valid JSON format. You can verify the validity of a JSON object using the function `json.dumps` from the *json* package.

Answer (score 1):

here's how :

```
payload = {2342,2354,5676,7423}
x = {"id": payload}
```

to have this:

`{"id": {2342,2354,5676,7423}}`

but this is not a valid JSON format

do you mean

```
payload = {"id": row}
```

to have something like this

```
{'id': [2342, 2354, 5676, 7423]}
```

Comment: Thank you! I was totally overthinking it. That totally worked. :)